# How do I retain format when getting text from Chrome Context menu?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension that allows a user to save a text snippet to their account (on a Python/Flask site). User flow...

1. User highlights text they want to save
2. Right-click and select the action I've added to the Chrome context menu
3. Popup window appears with selected text in a textarea within a form.  User can make final edits and Save to their account.

The problem is that formatting is not retained when displaying in the text area.  (Everything appears on one line)

I had this problem on my Python backend, but solved it with repr().  I searched for a JS equivalent, but no luck.

```
//eventPage.js
var contextMenuItem = {
    "id": "grabText",
    "title": "Save text",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};

chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData){
    if (clickData.menuItemId == "grabText" && clickData.selectionText){

        chrome.storage.local.set({snippet: clickData.selectionText}, function(){});
        chrome.windows.create({type: 'popup', focused: true, url: '/submitSnippet.html'}, function(){});

    }
})
```

```
//submitSnippet.js
  ...
$('#SnippetEntry').val(result.snippet);
  ...
```

```html
submitSnippet.html
  ...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="submitSnippet.js"></script>
  ...

<pre><textarea class="form-control mb-2" wrap="hard" id="SnippetEntry" rows="3" name="snippetinput"></textarea></pre>

...
```

When going through 1-3 above with:

```
The White House
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW
Washington, DC 20500
```

Everything goes to a single line. 


```
The White House 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500
```

Copy-pasting directly into my textarea retains the line breaks.  Is there something I can do in my JS to retain the formatting when using clickData.selectionText?

Comment: No, the API can't do that. You'll have to copypaste the text yourself using a temporary hidden textarea, there are lots of extensions doing that, look for examples around.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm.  Most extensions I have found use `selectionText` in `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked`.  I'll keep searching for one that just uses `window.getSelection()`.  I have tried that in my code but can't seem to access the window data from within an extensions event script.

Comment: No getSelection, but document.execCommand.